# window.scroll() function not firing

Tags: javascript, html, events, window, dom-events

I have a function that when a menu item is clicked it is supposed to cause the window to scroll by 400px;

When I click the menu item, the internal part of the function is firing because I am getting the console.log message, however the window isn't scrolling.  I can't seem to work out what the problem is.

Any help would be awesome.

Codepen:https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/LQVQrq

JS

```
var aboutLink = document.querySelector(".menu-item-1 a")

var menuClicked = false;

function aboutClicked () {

    if (menuClicked === false) {

        window.scroll(0, 400);
        menuClicked = true;
        console.log("clicked")

    }
}   

aboutLink.addEventListener("click", aboutClicked);
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu-item-1">
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you actually have 700px of window in height?

Comment: @Omer, I've changed it to 300px for the demo just in case, but that's not the problem.  It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have the default event prevented in the listener call. Below is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var aboutLink = document.querySelector(".menu-item-1 a");
                aboutLink.addEventListener("click", aboutClicked);

                var menuClicked = false;

                function aboutClicked(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    if (menuClicked === false) {

                        window.scroll(0, 500);
                        menuClicked = true;
                        console.log("clicked");

                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
```